# How to create a square-root symbol in non-math mode

Tags: symbols

I wish to write a pure-text square root symbol, like √. The purpose is to write an instruction as it is displayed on a simple calculator, i.e. something like `√(2+3)`. I am aware of `$\sqrt{}$`, but I don't want to use this because with an empty argument, the square root-sign is too low compared to the surrounding text. I could fix the position of the symbol using something like `$\sqrt{\color{white}{|}}$` (provided I have `xcolor` loaded) but the result isn't beautiful.

Is there a command to produce the √-symbol (such as we have `\$` for `$`)? Apparently `\√` doesn't exist.

Detexify suggests

- `$\surd$`, which is exactly a math-mode square root sign without argument.
- `\textsurd` (provided the package `textcomp`) comes close.

I wonder if there is an exact version of √, i.e. as one can use in other text-editors.

Comment: Try `$\surd$`...

Comment: Try also `$\sqrt{\mathstrut}$` or `$\sqrt{\vphantom{5}}$` ....

Comment: How about any of the above suggestions with `\newcommand\textsqrtsymbol{\mbox{$\sqrt{\mathstrut}$}}` where `$\sqrt{\mathstrut}$` can be replaced by whatever produces the symbol most to your liking.

Comment: How you can use the symbol in word processing applications is outside the scope of this site.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps this is a bad question indeed. Shall I delete it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can type the character `√` directly if you load `inputenc` with the option `utf8x`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

√(2+3)

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Is there any reason why one would not want to load `inputenc` with `utf8x`, i.e. does it conflict with other features?